# Explain verses 58:22 and 9:72

Tags: quran, tafseer

In 58:22 and 9:72 it is said that Allah is pleased with all believers:

> "You will not find a people who believe in Allah and the Last Day
> having affection for those who oppose Allah and His Messenger, even if
> they were their fathers or their sons or their brothers or their
> kindred. Those – He has decreed within their hearts faith and
> supported them with spirit from Him. **And We will admit them to
> gardens beneath which rivers flow, wherein they abide eternally. Allah
> is pleased with them, and they are pleased with Him** – those are the
> party of Allah.Unquestionably, the party of Allah – they are the
> successful. ([58] Al-Mujadila : 22)".

> **Allah has promised the believing men and believing women gardens**
> beneath which rivers flow, wherein they abide eternally, and pleasant
> dwellings in gardens of perpetual residence; but approval from Allah
> is greater. It is that which is the great attainment. ([9] At-Tawbah :
> 72)

It says here about all believers, judging by the words:"You will not find a people who believe in Allah and the Last Day...".But at the same time, most of the verses say:

> And give good tidings to those who believe and do righteous deeds that
> they will have gardens [in Paradise] beneath which rivers flow.
> Whenever they are provided with a provision of fruit therefrom, they
> will say, "This is what we were provided with before." And it is given
> to them in likeness. And they will have therein purified spouses, and
> they will abide therein eternally. ([2] Al-Baqarah : 25)

But my question is: if Paradise is promised to all believers in 58:22 and 9:72, then why is it necessary to have righteous deeds in other verses? Why is the word "to do righteous deeds" omitted in these two verses?

Please explain, I really need it.

Comment: The act of "doing righteous deeds" is a precursor to become *truly* among the "people who believe in Allah and the Last Day". The same way a Muslim, can be a *true* one, unless he actually commits on what it means to be a Muslim, they are two sides of the same coin.

Comment: Omar AlSuwaidi, 58:22 clearly refers to true Muslims. But the word "righteous deeds" is omitted for some reason. That's what I can't understand.

Comment: @lus, I told you brother, the omission does not mean that it's not necessary, it's basically **inferred** from the description of a true believer. Do I *always* have to say, "A Muslim who says: there is no God but Allah alone"? No, because that description is entailed when I say "Muslim."

Comment: @Omar AlSuwaidi, Brother, could you give me a link from the Koran where a Muslim is described as doing righteous deeds?